# Passing rows of a MatrixXd to a function to be modified without creating copies in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

This question is concerned with C++ and Eigen.

I have a function that computes some vector as `Eigen::VectorXd` and stores them into the vector passed as an argument. The return value of the function is the number of iterations done in the function. Below is the pseudocode of the function:

```
size_t integrate(Eigen::VectorXd& v) {
    size_t numIterations = 0;
    // do some iterative calculations and increment numIterations
    // vNew is generated from the new calculations
    v = vNew;
    return numIterations;
}
```

The way I'd like to use this function is as below:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd q = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(numRows, numCols);

for(size_t i = 0; i < numSteps; i++) {
    integrate(q.row(i));
}
```

However this won't compile in Visual Studio. I'm getting a `C++ initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue` compiler error. My intention is to avoid unnecessary copies and just place the calculation result (a vector) into the matrix in every iteration of the for loop. I understand that `row()` does not return a `VectorXd`. I've tried a few other things but none worked. What would be an efficient way of filling the rows of a preallocated `MatrixXd` in Eigen?

Note: I am aware that I could've just passed the matrix to the function by ref along with the current value of `i` and do `q.row(i) = vNew;` in `integrate()`. However it looks ugly and unnecessary to me. `integrate()` really doesn't have to know anything about a `MatrixXd`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass writable references to blocks of matrices using an `Eigen::Ref` object. In your case, since rows of (column major) matrices will have an inner stride, you need to explicitly allow that:

```
size_t integrate(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<> > v) {
    v.setRandom(); // use `v` as if it was a VectorXd
    return 0;
}
```

For better performance, you should consider either storing `q` in row major form, or passing individual columns to `integrate`:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> q; q.setZero(numRows, numCols);
// ...
integrate(q.row(i));
```

Or:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd q; q.setZero(numRows, numCols); // you'll need to switch how many rows and cols are to be allocated
// ...
integrate(q.col(i));
```

In either that case, `integrate` could take a simple `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>` (aka `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> >`):

```
size_t integrate(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd> v) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to get it to work by defining the function as ```size_t integrate(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd> v)``` and making the matrix ```q``` a column major matrix as you suggested. Just to be sure; would you use ```Eigen::Ref<>``` only to pass the values returned by functions such as ```.col()```, ```.head()``` etc. and not to pass a, say, ```Eigen::VectorXd```? I pass ```Eigen::VectorXd```s by reference without ```Eigen::Ref<>```. Is that correct?

Comment: `Eigen::Ref` essentially just contains a pointer to the data and the dimensions of the passed object. You can also pass a `VectorXd` via a `Ref`, but if you know that you will only pass `VectorXd` you might as well pass that directly (by `&` reference).

Comment: I understand. Thanks for all the clarifications.